# Get an instance of AmChart using ID / All the charts in AmCharts4 Angular-Typescript

Tags: amcharts

Earlier we used get them using this.AmCharts

AmCharts had provided us AmChartsService , using this we could get an hold of all the charts in the dom , with the upgrade what is the new way to get all the charts in the page ?

Comment: am4core.registry.baseSprites , gets all the instance but not by the div-id which we use for charts

Comment: Found it : am4core.registry.baseSprites[0].htmlContainer.id , can get you ids , please suggest if you find any better approaches.

Comment: What are you looking to do? What `id` are you referring to? The `id` of the node provided to `am4core.create()`? You need to get the actual chart object and according to the `id` of the node it was created in? What is insufficient/unsatisfactory about iterating through the `baseSprites` array and matching against `htmlContainer.id`?

Comment: It would be nice if there was a better way.  I need to dispose of a chart, but don't really have a reasonable mechanism of maintaining a reference to the chart.