# Amchart V4 export all existing amcharts together in a page

Tags: amcharts

How can I get all Amchart instances of my page in Amchart V4, like it was *this.AmChartsService.charts* in V3? I want to export them all together.

Comment: Did you look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/54821598/9662601?

Comment: But is it the only way to get all charts? Can't we pick them by id or class?

Comment: By what ID or class? Do you want the dom SVG, or the chart objects?

Comment: I want to pick chart objects but not all present in my DOM. want some specific charts those I know ID or class.

Comment: @Saumya do you still need to know how to export all the charts together? If so, is there a particular format you're exporting them as?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `am4core.registry.baseSprites` array and use the native JavaScript methods to filter it.

Find by html id:

```
var id = 'chartdiv';
var chart = am4core.registry.baseSprites.find(c => c.htmlContainer.id === id);
```

Find by html class name:

```
var className = 'my-class';
var chart = am4core.registry.baseSprites.find(c => Array.from(c.htmlContainer.classList).includes(className));
```

Find by chart id:

```
var id = 'myId';
var chart = am4core.registry.baseSprites.find(c => c.id === id);
```