# amCharts - Get chart object by HTML Element or id?

Tags: javascript, charts, amcharts

I'm trying to access the chart methods of a chart (amCharts 3.21.14) that has already been instantiated and it's in the DOM being displayed, but I don't have a reference to it other than the element itself.

How can I do this? Couldn't find it in the docs.

Something like this :

```
const chart = AmCharts.getChart('#my-chart');
console.log(chart)
```

I couldn't find anytning similiar [in the API reference](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v3/reference/amchart/)

*The reason I don't have access to the reference is because my code isn't the one that creates the chart, I'm working on a module that tries to export already existing charts.*

Comment: What you exactly want,

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54880956/9662601) answer or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54821598/9662601) question solve your problem?

Comment: @SamuelPhilipp - those are v4-specific. He's asking about v3.

Comment: I found a workaround by using the global AmCharts.charts list, it kinda works

Comment: @Mojimi - yeah there isn't a direct method for this. I was just about to suggest creating your own using the AmCharts.charts list as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a workaround by searching for the ID in the `AmCharts.charts` list (although the documentation does not mentions this)